# Scrapy: how to pass links

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I can not pass references. When starting a spider, I'm not getting data
Help with code.

I'm a beginner in Scrapy

```python
import scrapy
from movie.items import AfishaCinema

class AfishaCinemaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'afisha-cinema'
    allowed_domains = ['kinopoisk.ru']
    start_urls = ['https://www.kinopoisk.ru/premiere/ru/']

    def parse(self, response):
    links = response.css('div.textBlock>span.name_big>a').xpath(
        '@href').extract()
    for link in links:
        yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_moov,
                             dont_filter=True)

def parse_moov(self, response):
    item = AfishaCinema()
    item['name'] = response.css('h1.moviename-big::text').extract()
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are not getting the data is that you don't `yield` any from your `parse_moov` method. As per [the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse), parse method *must return an iterable of `Request` and/or dicts or `Item` objects*. So add

```
yield item
```

at the end of your `parse_moov` method.

Also, to be able to run your code, I had to modify

```
yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse_moov, dont_filter=True)
```

to

```
yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_moov, dont_filter=True)
```

in the `parse` method, otherwise I was getting errors:

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /film/monstry-na-kanikulakh-3-more-zovyot-2018-950968/
```

(That's because `Request` constructor needs absolute URL while the page contains relative URLs.)